# Как преобразовать ассоциативный массив?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив вида:

```
var mass_elem = {
  "A1" : {
    "bend" : "198",
    "asp"  : "155",
    "m2"   : "32"
  }, 
  "A2" : {
    "bend" : "100",
    "asp"  : "155",
    "m2"   : "32"
  },
  "A3" : {
    "bend" : "55",
    "asp"  : "155",
    "m2"   : "32"
  },   
}
```

Как этого  массива можно сделать массив вида:

```
var mass_elem_2 = {
  "A1": "198",
  "A2": "100",
  "A3": "55",
}
```

То есть нужно оставить значение из поля bend, а вместо ключа bend - ключ массива mass_elem. А остальные поля убрать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так как в вопросе не массивы, а объекты. Сначала нужно получить их ключи, и затем применить [метод `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var elem = {
  "A1": {
    "bend": "198",
    "asp": "155",
    "m2": "32"
  },
  "A2": {
    "bend": "100",
    "asp": "155",
    "m2": "32"
  },
  "A3": {
    "bend": "55",
    "asp": "155",
    "m2": "32"
  },
};

var result = Object.keys(elem).reduce(function(object, cur) {
  object[cur] = elem[cur].bend;
  return object;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: но ведь ассоциативный массив это и есть объект в JS, разве нет?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, конечно нет: объект - это не массив.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko воббще-то в  js всё является объектами, конкретно массив это [ ], смысл изговнять терминологию.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, вообще это вопрос терминологии. Просто большинство людей употребляющих термин _ассоциативный массив_, по отношению к объекту в JS, пришли из php, а там поведение массивов с нечисловыми ключами разительно отличается от поведения объектов в Js, поэтому лучше сразу разграничить данные термины.